# Can I use other python implementation via virtualenv/virtualenvwrapper?

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, pypy, virtualenvwrapper

After a while of searching (maybe it's not enough, but I don't think I'm making progress doing that), I haven't been able to find information about compatibility of other Python implementations in virtualenv/virtualenvwrapper.
By "other implementation" I mean things like PyPy, IronPython, Cython, Jython...

for example, I can create a virtualenv for a different python version using the following code .

`mkvirtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.6 new_venv`

but when I tried to create a virtualenv for PyPy by:

`mkvirtualenv -p /usr/bin/pypy new_venv`

system throws some error.

EDIT:
I'm using virtualenvwrapper-win. it throws

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter C:\pypy2-v5.8.0-win32\pypy.exe
New pypy executable in C:\Users\fangming.zfm\Envs\test-123\bin\pypy.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
system cannot find the path specified.
system cannot find the path specified.
system cannot find the path specified.
```

why we can't do this? is it because of lack of interest, or is it technically infeasible?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Do you have setuptools, pip and wheel packages installed with pypy outside of virtual env?

Comment: @phd, I installed pip using ```pypy -m ensurepip``` based on what i saw [here](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/install.html), but it seems still not solving my "system cannot find the path specified" problem.

Comment: Try `pypy -m pip install -U setuptools pip wheel`.

Comment: @phd, it's still the same error, now I wonder if I could dig deeper into that error message.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me:

```
$ mktmpenv -p pypy
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/pypy
New pypy executable in /home/phd/.virtualenvs/tmp-b29122e40f353f03/bin/pypy
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/phd/.virtualenvs/tmp-b29122e40f353f03/bin/predeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/phd/.virtualenvs/tmp-b29122e40f353f03/bin/postdeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/phd/.virtualenvs/tmp-b29122e40f353f03/bin/preactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/phd/.virtualenvs/tmp-b29122e40f353f03/bin/postactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/phd/.virtualenvs/tmp-b29122e40f353f03/bin/get_env_details
This is a temporary environment. It will be deleted when you run 'deactivate'

$ python --version
Python 2.7.8 (2.4.0+dfsg-3, Dec 20 2014, 13:30:11)
[PyPy 2.4.0 with GCC 4.9.2]
```

What exactly is your error?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to `pypy.exe` being located under the `/bin/` directory -- and not the `Scripts` directory (like virtualenvwrapper-win expects).

There's an issue for it (https://github.com/davidmarble/virtualenvwrapper-win/issues/30) and it should be relatively simple to fix.